# Questions about passing variables in C

Tags: c

I'm familiar with Pascal, using it at work I can do things like this

```
SomeVar = 1

and in my code I can plug this into another variable:

differentVariable = MyVariable[SomeVar] ...
```

The code in between the brackets is substituted with the value of SomeVar.
So the compiler reads 
    MyVariable[SomeVar] as MyVariable1
I call it passing the variable, not sure what the correct term is.

I'm hoping there is an equivalent operation in C and someone can point me in the right direction.

I'm using atmel studio right now trying to pass a variable from a for loop to another int variable

```
int LED1 = PB0;
int LED2 = PB1;
etc...

while(1)

 for(x=0; x<10; x++)
{ LED[x] = 1;
}
```

Something like this

Comment: You need to use an array, there is no such thing in C.

Comment: You could also use preprocessor macros, but an array is probably the right choice in most situations.

Comment: Even in pascal array variables—like `MyVariable`—have to declared as such. You need to do the same thing in c.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create Array.

This is how you declare it:

```
    int LED[N]
```

N here is number of elements that you can put in this array.

And now you got an Array of elements. You can put element in it with your for loop.
 Example:

```
   LED[0] = 2 //This is how you give value of 2 to 0 element of an Array
   LED[2] = 2 //This is how you give value of 2 to 2. element of an Array
```

It will work with for loop you created